# Is a lone return statement valid Lua code?

Tags: function, lua, pandoc

In the pandoc [introduction to filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#introduction) the following code is presented as an "example of a Lua filter":

```
return {
  {
    Strong = function (elem)
      return pandoc.SmallCaps(elem.c)
    end,
  }
}
```

I have never seen a standalone return statement in Lua as shown in the example above. Furthermore I cannot see this syntax documented anywhere in the official [reference](https://lua.org/docs.html).

Could anyone please let me know the following:

- Whether this is valid Lua?
- Where it is documented in the Lua [docs](https://lua.org/docs.html)?

Comment: You can find all lua syntax in the chapter [The Complete Syntax of Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9). It's called **retstat** or **laststat**.

Comment: @shingo Perfect. Nice that they have the complete grammar on there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is valid Lua. Lua files  or strings are called "chunks" and are basically functions and may thus contain `return` statements like any other function. Their arguments are accessible through the vararg `...`.

This is documented in the [Lua 5.4 reference manual section on Chunks](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.2):

> Lua handles a chunk as the body of an anonymous function with a variable number of arguments (see §3.4.11). As such, chunks can define local variables, receive arguments, and return values.

---

When starting a Lua file from the command line, `...` will be the command line arguments. When manually [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load)ing strings or [`loadfile`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-loadfile)ing files, you get the chunk returned as a function and can decide what you want to pass.

---

In fact it is considered good practice to `return` something from a `require`d file rather than writing your library functions to the global namespace. `return` is in that case equivalent to JS `export`:

`foo.lua`:

```lua
return function()
    print("foo")
end
```

`bar.lua`:

```lua
local foo = require("foo")
foo()
```